# Объеденение таблиц laravel

Tags: php, laravel, таблицы

Имею две таблицы
Users(id, name, country)
Countries(id, country, city)
Как мне правильно сформировать запрос чтобы получить в массиве id,name,country, city?
Пробовал через `hasOne` в модельке `Users`

```
public function country(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Countries', 'country', 'country');
    }
```

В котроллере

```
Users::orderBy('id', 'desc')->country()->get();
```

по разному пробовал ничего не выходит, возможно обязательно нужно сделать ответный `belongsTo` правильно ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Не `country`, а `country_id`. И не `country`, а `name`. По хорошему надо и `city` выносить в отдельную страницу.

```
Users(id, name, country_id)
Countries(id, name, city)
```

2) Соответственно модель. Модель должны быть в единственном числе - название файлов модели и классов модели. Всё в единственном. А названия таблиц в БД - во множественном. Почитайте про соглашения имён в laravel

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Country');
}
```

3) Запрос. Если вы хотите получить и данные из таблицы `users`, и данные из таблицы `countries`, тогда так (опять же - модели в единственном числе)

```
User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->with('country')->get();
```

`with()` - добавляет данные по запрошенной связи к результату запроса в виде подмассива.

Касательно обратной связи - это не обязательно. Указываете только те связи, которые используете.

Если вы следуете соглашению по именованию, то вы себе сильно упрощаете жизнь. Для кого вообще [делают курсы](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7FQEutaCiQ&index=1&list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme)? Субтитры присутствуют.

Comment: я получаю в таблицу Users как раз имя страны, могу максимум переименовать в country_name...

Comment: А есть способ чтобы не подмассивом?

Comment: но у вас же имя страны уже указано в таблице `Countries`. Зачем дублируете информацию, да ещё так отвратительно

Comment: есть. Самый простой вариант - собрать новый массив руками